# How to get images from a saved html page

Tags: html, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have a huge amount of saved HTML pages in my PC. I had parsed the the HTML page and got the image src. I need to store the images in every HTML page in a specific structure in separate directory. I tried out NET::HTTP.get but i am getting a error of Filename too long. Is there any  way to do this ??

Below are the ways i tried out.

Method 1:

```
{
require 'open-uri'

def save_image(imgsrc)
    File.open("images/img1","w") do |f|
        asdf = open(imgsrc).read
        f.write(asdf)
    end
end
}
```

Method 2:

```
{
require 'NET::HTTP'

def save_image(imgsrc)
    File.open("images/img1","w") do |f|
        asdf = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(imgsrc)
        f.write(asdf)
    end
end
}


imgsrc => data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Comment: Why do you wrap your code in `{...}`?

Comment: @the Tin Man This is my first question.  In the instructions it was mentioned that the code should be within the {}. That's why i did it

Comment: The code doesn't have to be inside `{...}`. Doing so only makes your code look wrong. The [advanced editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) describes how to format text as code.

Comment: Thnaks for your mention tin. i would definitely follow it up hereafter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the images, the one you posted(in the `imgsrc` variable) is

[image: this image]

You only need to decode it using [base64](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) module, and save the result to a file.

To decode your image i've used [this service](http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/).

---

To decode using Base64 you should use `#strict_decode64` method:

```
$ cat testb64.rb

imgsrc='/9j/4AAQS... ...oooA//2Q==' #( snipped here your long variable, 
                                    #  removed "data:image/jpeg;base64," 
                                    #  from the beginning )
require 'base64'
print Base64.strict_decode64(imgsrc)

$ ruby testb64.rb >img.jpg

$ xxd -p img.jpg 
ffd8ffe000104a464946....

(valid JFIF header, viewable JPEG by Gwenview and Dolphin)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Eugene Petrov. The link which you provided is working but when using Base64.decode64(imgsrc), i am getting some binary value. On saving that into a file i dont get the image.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I too have figured it out from your answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
require 'open-uri'

require 'base64'
require 'open-uri'

def save_image(imgsrc)
  File.open("images/img1", "wb") do |fo|
    fo.write(Base64.decode64(open(imgsrc).read))
  end
end
```

It will save to the file path `"images/img1"` so you'll want to create separate paths for each file otherwise they'll overwrite each one.

`"wb"` means to open the output file using binary mode, which avoids line-end translations appropriate for your OS. Without `b`, Ruby will look for "\r" and "\n" and either remove or add them as necessary for a text file, which will corrupt a binary file. `b` avoids that step. This is documented in the [`IO.new` description](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode).

You can't pass

```
imgsrc => data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

as the URL for an image, as that isn't a URL. Both OpenURI and Net::HTTP expect a URL to the image, which they will then request and read the resulting response, returning the data back to your code. You'd need to do a Base64 decode against that data, which will result in a binary string in memory, which you can then write to a file opened in binary mode.

Comment: Thanks for ur detailed explanation. I got to made it work yesterday !!